# Get IP of VM running on an Ubuntu server configured on bridged networking

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, virtualbox, headless

I want to set up an exported VM on an Ubuntu Server using VirtualBox on headless mode.

I have the VM up and running and bridged with the ethernet interface of the host (em1), so the dhcp of the host should now assign an IP to the VM if I'm not mistaken.

Is there a way to check if this is working and if yes to get the VM's IP?
Since this is on headless mode so without GUI, the only way to login to the VM is through ssh and for that I need the IP..

Answer (score 1):

**welthenwel**, 
you can do this with VBoxManage.
from a shell, just type:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate VM_NAME --pattern */IP
```

and you will get as response something like in the below image.

[image]

*now, ignore the fact that I run this cmd from a Windows host, because its behaves exactly the same from inside a linux host*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the command responds with "no properties found". Does that mean the bridging didn't work?

Comment: for my VM, the network settings for Attached to is [Bridged Adapter]. If cmd doesn't work, could be something wrong in VMs config. Do you have Guest Additions installed on VM?

Comment: I don't know what the VM has or has not installed since I can't log in to it.. In the snapshot below you can see the VM's info:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmerg427lduk4ht/vm_info.png?dl=0               The NIC1 interface is set to bridged with the host's ethernet (em1), doesn't that mean that it's properly configured?

Comment: well, properly configured can mean different thing for us. In this case, it's clear that something is missing.but, pls take a look here (how to install guest additions on a headless vm): https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&p=78127

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with VirtualBox. Bridged with VMWare Workstation meant the IP is given by your default DHCP server, which means you could look up the assigned IP address there (e.g. your router - if you have access to it).

Another option would be a ping sweep of your network segment as I believe Ubuntu doesn't drop ICMP requests.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have access to the router since this is a university. I'll try the ping sweep